# Custom routing and handling form submission

Tags: php, routes, silverstripe

I have some custom routing:

```
---
Name: mysiteroutes
---
Director:
  rules:
    'signup//$Action/$Data/$Form': 'SignupController'
---
Name: modelascontrollerroutes
After: '#rootroutes'
---
Director:
  rules:
    '': 'HomePage_Controller'
    '$URLSegment/$Action/$ID': 'BaseController'
```

And a signup controller:

```
class SignupController extends Page_Controller {

    private static $allowed_actions = array(
        'submit'
    );

    public function index(SS_HTTPRequest $request) {
        $form = Form::create(
            $this,
            __FUNCTION__,
            FieldList::create(
                EmailField::create('Email', 'Email')
            ),
            FieldList::create(
                FormAction::create('submit', 'Submit')->setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-success')
            ),
            RequiredFields::create('Email')
        );
        return $this->customise(array('Form'=>$form))->renderWith(array("Signup", "Page"));
    }

    public function submit($data, $form = null) {
        $form->addErrorMessage("Test", "Test error message",'bad');
        return $this->redirectBack();
    }
}
```

The form is presented however no error messages get displayed. When I go to submit it it goes to (of course) SignupController/submit which returns a 404. I've added `setFormAction(Controller::join_links(BASE_URL, "signup", 'submit'))` to the `$form` and the data comes through however the `$form` is null and I cannot update it. I could potentially make it an instance variable however I can probably solve this using the correct SS routing. Should I be updating my routing to get the `$form` or is something else wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need the `$Data` and `$Form` parameters in the routing, these will be in the POST data.

Secondly, you don't need to have the `submit` method in your `allowed_actions` as it won't be triggered by a route.

To fix this you should;
add a function Link

```
public function link($action = null)
{
    return $this->join_links('signup', $action);
}
```

So you will be redirected to `signup/...`

Then change your index function to this;

```
public function index() {
    $form = Form::create(
        $this,
        '', //so it will redirect you to 'signup', instead of 'signup/index'; I think it's prettier :)
        FieldList::create(
            EmailField::create('Email', 'Email')
        ),
        FieldList::create(
            FormAction::create('submit', 'Submit')
                ->setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-success')
        ),
        RequiredFields::create('Email')
    );

    if($this->request->isPost()) 
        return $form; //return the form when it gets posted

    return $this->customise(array('Form'=>$form))->renderWith(array("Signup", "Page"));
}
```